# Microsoft Project 2016 - Change Field Drop Down List

Tags: ms-project

I'm new to MS Projects 2016. I did some searches on this topic but didn't get an easy solution. Hence I'm creating this question.

MS Project has a built-in field (column) called Status and it seems to come with default values (Late, On Schedule) - maybe it's calculated. If my project wants this Status field to has a dropdown list for user to select from (Complete, Scheduled, Not Scheduled). How should I proceed?

Our least preference is to create a custom field with another name.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to customise the behaviour of this field, MS Project will always automatically calculate the values it displays according to the rules you'll see in the help topic for that column. You will need to work with a custom field to achieve what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

As Jon metioned, you can't customize the Status field. However, [customizing other fields is very easy](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-custom-field-839d206f-b314-48f5-aa06-79140db93b94). In this case, use a Text field (e.g. Text1) and provide a custom list of values. On the Tools menu, point to Customize, and then click Fields. Select Text under Type (upper right). Click Lookup... and add the values you want.

[image: Custom Field settings]

Then add the Text1 field to the Gantt table to see this:

[image]